# Select by location polygon due south of selected polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, select-by-location

I am working with a layer of tax lots (MapPLUTO in NYC) and am interested in identifying which lot is due south of a subset of tax lots.

Is there any way to use the 'select by' functionality in QGIS to identify only the southern adjacent polygon of a polygon in a layer?

Image below shows the tax lot data with selected tax lots highlighted. I'm interested in creating a new selection of the tax lot immediately south of each of these.

[image: Screenshot of tax lot map with highlighted lots in yellow]

I'm interested in southern sun exposure at a subset of tax lots and would like to identify and analyze the tax lots that could be blocking the sun at some of these lots.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you are after from the question and screenshot. You might need to go into a bit more specifics, and post some sample data in order to get assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this in pyqgis editor to get plots that are south, east and west from your plot of interest. Perhaps you could rotate the features and use minimum y to get just the south features or / and to set a max x coordinate.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

box = layer.boundingBoxOfSelected()
#selection_y_min = box.yMinimum()
selection_y_max = box.yMaximum()


#query = 'y_max($geometry) <= ' + str(selection_y_min)
query = 'y_max($geometry) < ' + str(selection_y_max)

request = QgsFeatureRequest(QgsExpression(query))
selection = layer.getFeatures(request)

layer.selectByIds([s.id() for s in selection])
```

[image]

[image]

[image]